# Parse json for sectioned UITableView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I am trying to display State (in section title) and City (in table rows) from [this url](https://raffleweb.cloudapp.net/api/public/GetPublicRaffleInstanceLocations?PublicRaffleInstanceId=506). Top Cities will come in first section followed by state and cities. Issue is I am not able to assign respective array of cities for sectioned state title row. Here's what I tried..

```
NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    NSLog(@"Json dictionary = %@", json);
    self.dictListSateMaster = [json objectForKey:@"RaffleInstanceLocations"];
    for (NSDictionary *dict in [self.dictListSateMaster objectForKey:@"listStateMaster"])
    {
        ViewLocationsObjct *viewLocationsObjct = [[ViewLocationsObjct alloc] init];
        viewLocationsObjct.StateNameStr = [dict objectForKey:@"StateName"];
        [self.arrayListStateMaster addObject:[dict objectForKey:@"StateName"]];
        for (NSDictionary *dictnry in [dict objectForKey:@"listCityMaster"])
        {
            //*********-- Need corrections here
            ViewLocationStateMaster *viewLocNewObjct = [[ViewLocationStateMaster alloc] init];
            viewLocNewObjct.CityName = [dictnry objectForKey:@"CityName"];
            [self.arrayListCityMaster addObject:viewLocNewObjct];
        }
    }

    for (NSDictionary *dict in [self.dictListSateMaster objectForKey:@"listTopCities"])
    {
        ViewLocationsObjct *viewLocationsObjct = [[ViewLocationsObjct alloc] init];
        viewLocationsObjct.CityName = [dict objectForKey:@"CityName"];
        [self.arrayTopCities addObject:viewLocationsObjct];
    }

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return self.arrayListStateMaster.count+1; //+1 to append to top cities section at the top
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellId = @"cellId";
    ViewLocationsTblCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        ViewLocationsObjct *viewLocationObj = [self.arrayTopCities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.locationLabl.text = viewLocationObj.CityName;
    }
    else
    {
        //*********-- Need corrections here
        //NSString *sectionTitle = [self.arrayListStateMaster objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        //NSMutableArray *arrayCities = [self.dictListSateMaster objectForKey:sectionTitle];
        //cell.locationLabl.text = [arrayCities objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        ViewLocationStateMaster *viewLoc = [self.arrayListCityMaster objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.locationLabl.text = viewLoc.CityName;
    }
    return cell;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (section == 0)//return top cities for 1st section
    {
        return self.arrayTopCities.count;
    }
    else
    {
        return self.arrayListCityMaster.count;
    }
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (section == 0)
    {
        return @"Top Cities";
    }
    else
    {
        if (self.arrayListStateMaster.count > 0)
        {
            return [self.arrayListStateMaster objectAtIndex:section-1];//-1 to remove index of top cities section at the top
        }
        else
        {
            return @"";
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need an array of arrays where the inner arrays are the cities for a given state.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK so here's how my problem was solved !

```
    NSDictionary *dictRaffleInstLocations = [json objectForKey:@"RaffleInstanceLocations"];
        sectionArray = [dictRaffleInstLocations objectForKey:@"listStateMaster"];
  topCityArray = [dictRaffleInstLocations objectForKeyedSubscript:@"listTopCities"];

   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
        return topCityArray.count;
    }else
        return [[[sectionArray objectAtIndex:section-1]objectForKey:@"listCityMaster"] count];

}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return sectionArray.count+1;
}


- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 0) {
        return @"Top Cities";
    }else
        return [[sectionArray objectAtIndex:section-1]objectForKey:@"StateName"];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellId = @"MyCellLocation";
    ViewLocationsTblCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellId forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion.floatValue >= 8.0f)
    {
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
        cell.preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins = NO;
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    NSString *titleString = @"";

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        titleString = [[topCityArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"CityName"];
    }else{

        NSArray *cityArray = [sectionArray[indexPath.section-1]objectForKey:@"listCityMaster"];
        titleString = [cityArray[indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"CityName"];
    }

    cell.locationLabl.text = titleString;

    return cell;
}
```